# Regex capture a number of words but exclude if another set of words is present

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a regex formula to match when two words are present `google` and `apple` but exclude `facebook` and `twitter` but I am having loads of problems

I tried this

```
^(?!.*(facebook|twitter)).*
```

But I also want to exclude anything is not `google` or `apple`

expected output:

```
'https://facebook/google'  --> Exclude
'https://twitter/google'   --> Exclude
'https://google/foo'       --> Include
'https://apple/'           --> Include
'https://twitter/apple'    --> Exclude
'https://nomatch'          --> Exclude
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking maybe it's good to check for exact words to avoid possible false negatives (e.g: 'apple' in 'apples'):

```
^(?!.*?\/(?:facebook|twitter)(?:\/|$)).*?\/(?:google|apple)(?:\/|$).*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4lFZ9y/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(?!` - Open negative lookahead;

  - `.*?\/` - 0+ (Lazy) characters upto a forward slash;
  - `(?:facebook|twitter)` - A nested non-capture group with the two alternations;
  - `(?:\/|$)` - A 2nd non-capture group to assert previous words are followed by a forward slash or end-string anchor;
  - `)` - Close negative lookahead;
- `.*?\/` - 0+ (Lazy) characters upto a forward slash;
- `(?:google|apple)` - A non-capture group with the two alternations;
- `(?:\/|$)` - Another non-capture group to assert previous words are followed by a forward slash or end-string anchor;
- `.*$` - 0+ (Greedy) characters upto the end-string anchor.

---

As per your comments, there seem to be quite a couple of specifics (leading/trailing dot's/hyphen or else). Therefor maybe add all these to a character class or accept that a word-boundary might be good enough for you:

```
^(?!.*?\b(?:facebook|twitter)\b).*?\b(?:google|apple)\b.*$
```

Comment: What about if it has www I dont mind about this part `http://www` just the words

Comment: What do you mean exactly @Álvaro. Do you want to exclude this from a match?

Comment: This works for me the other was too restrictive `^(?!.*(facebook|twitter)).*(apple|google)` it did not work if it had `www` otherwise

Comment: Would `^(?!.*?[\/.](?:facebook|twitter)(?:[\/.]|$)).*?[\/.](?:google|apple)(?:[\/.]|$).*$` work for you in that case? It's simply an edit to allow for both forward slash or a dot in our class. And still won't allow for false-positives.

Comment: Yeah that works too, but it's a lot more complex

Comment: It's not that complex tbh @Álvaro and just adds a little more security... keep in mind that your own attempt does not destinguish between 'apple' and 'apples' or 'twitter' and 'twitters'.

Comment: This one is not going to be capture thou `https://nymag.com/strategist/article/best-apple-joue-we-vibe-dame.html` And it should cause it has `apple`

Comment: @Álvaro, all these specific cases. Please include those in your initial question. Two options here; add the hyphen to the character class or replace those entirely with word-boundaries `\b` if you happy with that.

Comment: Yeah this is the thing with regex you end up having to be so especific that it starts getting too complicated, the one I have adapted from your response works for me even thou apples and twitters gets matched, thanks